# Can't get Amazon S3 Cross Region Replication between two accounts to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm hoping someone can help me with an Amazon S3 Cross Region Replication query. I have two Amazon AWS accounts, each with a bucket in a different region. I want to replicate the data from one bucket to another and from what I understand this should be a simple process to create. However, I'm really struggling and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've followed a lot of instructions online including going through various AWS tutorials, seeing lots of examples, but I can't get the data to replicate.

I have enabled versioning on both buckets and none of the data is encrypted. However I do have a policy in my source bucket that permits access to the source data through a referral condition so that the data (images in this case) can only be accessed through specific domains. This all works fine and I have a suspicion that this is what is perhaps restricting access from the destination bucket.

I have followed online instructions to set up the replication rules and IAM policies.

So, my source bucket policy is:-

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referrer policy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow get requests originated from list",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOURCEBUCKET/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.domain1.com/*",
                    "https://www.domain2.com/*",
                    "http://domain3.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

and my destination bucket policy is:-

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "S3-Console-Replication-Policy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "S3ReplicationPolicyStmt1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MYSOURCEACCIDNUMBER:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
            "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
            "s3:ReplicateObject",
            "s3:ReplicateDelete"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::DESTINATIONBUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::DESTINATIONBUCKET/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Can anyone advise me on how I can (if I need to) add to the source bucket policy that will enable access from the destination bucket? I'm pretty confident the issue is here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this situation, I did the following:

- Created `Bucket-A` in `Account-A` with versioning
- Created `Bucket-B` in `Account-B` with versioning
- Configured Cross-Region Replication on `Bucket-A`, selecting "Create new role" (see below)
- Added the destination bucket policy provided in the UI (matching yours, above) to `Bucket-B`

The process **created a role** called `s3crr_role_for_bucket-a_to_bucket-b` that contains:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then uploaded a file to `Bucket-A` and it **successfully replicated** to `Bucket-B`.

So, the process seems to work fine. If you are having difficulties, some thoughts are:

- Make sure there are no policies that might be applying a `DENY` against the bucket
- Check the **IAM Role** that was assigned to CRR and ensure it is granting permissions as shown above
- Check [Troubleshooting Cross-Region Replication - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-troubleshoot.html)
- See also [Cross-Region Replication Status Information - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-status.html)

Comment: Thanks John. I deleted the rule in the source bucket and re-created it again. The only difference is I let the process create the role and that actually worked! Thanks. Is there any way to sync existing files to the destination bucket? I.e. the process of replication works but only for new files. What about all the stuff that's already in the source bucket?

Comment: No, it will not replica any history. You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with `aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket/ s3://destination-bucket` to copy existing content.

Answer (score 0):

Letting the replication rule setup create the new IAM role also worked for me when the identical manually created policy was failing. When comparing the auto-created role and my manually created role, the difference was the working autocreated role was a **service-role** and my nonworking role was an *instance-role*.

Double check the IAM role used on the source bucket for replication is a service role or regular role, but NOT an instance profile role.