# Why S3 cross-region replication is not working for us when we're upload a file with PHP?

Tags: amazon-s3

S3 cross region replication is not working for us when we're upload a file with PHP.
When we upload the file from the AWS interface it replicate to the other bucket it's working great, but when we use S3 API for PHP: *putObject* it's upload but don't replicate to the other bucket.

What are we missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some errors?

Comment: @dmitry No. I can put the object on the bucket, it's just don't replicate when I do that with the code.

Comment: Can you show us the bucket policy of the upload bucket, the bucket policy of the destination bucket, and the permissions granted to whatever IAM role / user the PHP is using?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, it would be great to see the bucket policy of the upload bucket, the bucket policy of the destination bucket, and the permissions granted to whatever IAM role / user the PHP is using.

My *guess* is that there's some difference in config/permissioning between the source bucket's owning account (which is likely what you use when manipulating from the AWS Console interface) and whatever account or role or user is representing your PHP code. For example:

> [If the owner of the source bucket doesn't own the object in the bucket, the object owner must grant the bucket owner READ and READ_ACP permissions with the object access control list (ACL)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html)

---

Pending more info from the OP, I'll add some potentially helpful trouble-shooting resources:

[Can't get amazon S3 cross-region replication between two accounts to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108781/cant-get-amazon-s3-cross-region-replication-between-two-accounts-to-work?rq=1)

[AWS Troubleshooting Cross-Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-troubleshoot.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is the same for replicating buckets between accounts, but I use this policy to replicate objects uploaded on a bucket in us-east-1 to a bucket in eu-west-1 and it works like a charm, both uploading files manually of from a python script.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3-Console-Replication-Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3ReplicationPolicyStmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS Account ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<replicated region ID>.<replicated bucket name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<replicated region ID>.<replicated bucket name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where:
 -  is, of course, your AWS account ID
 -  is the AWS region ID (eu-west-1, us-east-1, ...) where the replicated bucket will be (in my case is eu-west-1)
 -  is the name of bucket you want to replicate. 
So say you want to replicate a bucket called "my.bucket.com" in eu-west-1, the Resource ARN to put in the policy will be `arn:aws:s3:::eu-west-1.my.bucket.com`. Same with the leading /*

Also the replication rule is set as follows:
 - Source: entire bucket
 - Destination: the bucket I mentioned above
 - Destination options: leave all unchecked
 - IAM role: Create new role
 - Rule name: give it a significant name
 - Status: Enabled